# Toggle tooltip content(Kendo) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, tooltip

I have a kendo tooltip setup for a button which looks like this..
[image]

And the code is here

```
// JS
var labels = { tt_piechart_text: "Show Pie Chart", tt_piechart_hide: "Hide Pie Chart"  }
$("#pieChartBtn").kendoTooltip({
        position: "bottom"
    });
// HTML
<input id="pieChartBtn" type="button" class="pieChartBtn" title="{{tt_piechart_text}}">
```

This is work fine until I want to change the content of tooltip to "Hide Pie Chart" when the button is clicked or active. This is the code I'm trying..

```
$('#pieChartBtn').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $("#pieChartBtn").data("kendoTooltip").popup.wrapper.find(".k-tooltip-content").html("{{tt_piechart_text}}");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#pieChartBtn").data("kendoTooltip").popup.wrapper.find(".k-tooltip-content").html("{{tt_piechart_hide}}");
    }
    $('#pieChartBtn').toggle();
});
```

The code is partially achieving what i want. Only problem now is,  `{{tt_piechart_text}}` and `{{tt_piechart_hide}}` are getting rendered as string. Like this..
[image]
[image]

I want the expressions to be rendered to equivalent strings. What am I missing here? How to fix this? I'm using Angular 1X and Kendo tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the k-content attribute and update the html from the controller as shown in the demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/angular